# Slow down CPU when it heats up

Tags: linux, gentoo, cpu, cpu-frequency, temperature

I run Gentoo Linux on my laptop. I have an issue, though, where if I'm building some very large piece of software (as I do fairly frequently, since the purpose of this laptop is development), the CPU tends to heat up more than I'd like.

I used to use `cpufreqd` to manage this, since it has an `lm_sensors` plugin and can reduce the CPU frequency once it reaches a particular temperature threshold.

However, this is no longer going to be a good option, since (apparently) `cpufreqd` is no longer actively maintained, and as such is going to be removed from Gentoo's package tree.

Because of this, my question is: **is there some other way I can solve this problem**?

I am aware of other similar CPU frequency management daemons, as well as the drivers that are built into the Linux kernel, but as far as I know they do not manage CPU frequency *as a function of CPU temperature*.

Comment: You might also want to look at the fan. My old laptop (Dell Latitude 400) used to heat up while doing large file transfers @ 1000Mb/s. You would hear the fan speed up after 30-40seconds and I would have a few seconds to stop the transfer. After cleaning out the dust from the fan things worked fine.

Comment: Definitely good advice in general, however this is a very new laptop so this shouldn't be an issue (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are still a couple of options left, please refer to [Arch wikipage](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling).

The one you are looking for, specifically, is [thermald](https://github.com/01org/thermal_daemon).

Comment: It looks like this will actually do exactly what I want. It's probably worth noting for others though that `thermald` is specifically for Intel processors. My laptop happens to have a modern i7, so this will work great. Thanks! :)